# How to filter Realm objects via an NSDate property

Tags: swift, nsdate, realm

I'm trying to filter Realm objects to find those with `createdAt` dates less than year ago:

```
let datex = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(NSDate()).dateByAddingTimeInterval(-1*365*24*60*60)
let list = RealmDB.objects(TaskList).filter("createdAt <= '\(datex)'")
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Expected object of type date for property 'createdAt' on object of type 'TaskList', but received: '2015-03-19 21:00:00 +0000'

How do I fix this? It also looks like the date and time value are adjusted to time zone. How can I make sure the date is really the end of the day?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you're using Swift's string interpolation to build your predicate rather than using `NSPredicate`'s argument substitution. This results in your predicate being something like:

```
createdAt <= '2015-03-19 07:00:00 +0000'
```

This is attempting to compare `createdAt`, a date, with a string literal. Using `NSPredicate`'s argument substitution would look like:

```
let list = RealmDB.objects(TaskList).filter("createdAt <= %@", datex)
```

Note that the way you're computing the date isn't correct in the face of leap days, leap seconds, discontinuities due to daylight savings, and so forth. You should use `NSCalendar`'s methods for date math rather than doing math with magic constants:

```
let calendar = NSCalender.currentCalendar()
let datex = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Year, value: -1, toDate: calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate()), options: [.MatchFirst])
```

Keep in mind that an `NSDate` represents a single point in time, independent of any time zone. The default formatting of `NSDate`, used when `-[NSDate description]` is called, happens to format the date in UTC. If you'd like to format the date to a string using a different time zone, you can use `NSDateFormatter` and set the time zone explicitly.